# Bit numbering in binary data with little endianness

Tags: binary, bit

> More formally, the 16 bytes of plaintext p0 ,..., p15 are first split into 4 words P0,...,P3 of 32 bits each using the little-endian convention.

In the above sentence, the plain word for example `this_is__awesome` contains 16 characters, I wonder which side is p0 and after splitting the plain text into 4 words `this`, `_is_`, `_awe`, `some`, which of these is P0?

Considering the term 'little endianess', `0x1234` would result in `0x34 0x12`, So I wonder this would become [`some`, `_awe`, `_is_`, `this`] if we apply little endianess to words, or would it become [`emos`, `ewa_`, `_si_`, `siht`] if we apply little endianess at byte level.

[image]

and finally what would Pi become for the plain text `this_is__awesome`
Please help me out with this.

Comment: p0 is `t`and P0 is `this`

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING won't get you an answer any faster. It's also rather impolite to come here and SHOUT at us when asking for free help. Thanks.

Comment: Please look at the question once again, I've updated it.